# How can I modify the code in taxonomy feature to include terms

Tags: features

I have created a feature to export my taxonomy vocabulary.  How can I programatically modify it to add the terms as well ?

Answer (score 1):

Features can't export (and import) terms without "extension".
You could use [UUID Features](https://www.drupal.org/project/uuid_features):

> The UUID Features Integration module provides a mechanism for
>   exporting content (nodes, taxonomy, fields) into a features module.

Comment: I was told that was buggy.  Is there a way to add the field terms programmatically to the features file?

Comment: You could try to add a .install file in the features and, with hook_install, create terms programmatically

Answer (score 1):

I always find https://www.drupal.org/project/deploy to be a reliable module to send content from one Drupal site to another. This also keeps content out of your version control.